# Pytesseract not reading correct word

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using the following code to read text from the attached image. I expect it to read 0.01, but it is actually outputting 201. Any suggestions on how to improve the accuracy for this image would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pytesseract
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2np
import cv2

img = Image.open('test.png')
processed_image = np.asarray(img)
processed_image = cv2.cvtColor(processed_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
processed_image = cv2.threshold(processed_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(processed_image, config='--psm 7').strip()
print(text)
```

The output is 201 for the following image, which actually says 0.01

[image]

Comment: Did you try searching for _tesseract improve accuracy_? There are plenty of results.

Comment: Actually, it worked by removing the cv2.threshold call, and changing to --psm 8.